# How to deal optionnal hour format in pandas to_datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, time, timestamp, string-formatting

I need to deal with a Dataframe of string (a run course btw) where people finish before one hour so it is formated "%M:%S" eg: "54:45" and some people finish after 1 hour, so the format is "%H:%M:%S" eg: "1:05:11"

Here some code to test:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['1:01:16','1:05:11','1:08:43','1:03:30','57:43']})
```

pandas doesn't like the mixed format and tell me this error:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
```

> ValueError: time data "57:43" doesn't match format "%H:%M:%S", at
> position 4. You might want to try:
> - passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
> - passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
> - passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside
> this.

So I have tried the format='mixed', but I also get this error:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],format='mixed').dt.time
```

> DateParseError: hour must be in 0..23: 57:43, at position 4

What are your ideas to deal that properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert both formats separately with `errors='coerce'` parameter for `NaT` for non matched format with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replacement this values:

```
df['time'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['time'],format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
                .fillna(pd.to_datetime(df['time'],format='%M:%S', errors='coerce'))
                .dt.time)
print (df)
       time
0  01:01:16
1  01:05:11
2  01:08:43
3  01:03:30
4  00:57:43
```